# Zend 2 login application

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form

This is my first time using Zend Studio and I am trying to create Zend2 Login Application.
I need help with creating simple login form where I can able to submit my form. Since this is my first time on zend2 so it is hard for me to create simple application with following rule of zend2.
Any help will work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to have a look at [ZfcUser](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser), a Zend Framework 2 module for managing user registration and authentication. It comes already with working routes and forms. Then, if you want, you could customize the look and feel and also how the module works overriding some components or better using the events that the module is exposing